# Pandas iloc or transpose slice transpose

Tags: python, pandas

Whilst I know both yield the same result which is more efficient and why.

```
#dataframe with shape 20,20
#slicing the first 10 columns

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(400).reshape(20,20))

df.T[:10].T
#or 
df.iloc[:,:10]
```

It's likely that the difference is negligible and the `iloc` is best practice because it is more readable. I'd like to know some pros and cons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.iloc[]` has been specially designed to be as efficient as possible. Performing two transposes involves a lot of data movement and is bound to be slower.

The performance difference between the two is measurable, and gets more significant as the size of the dataframe increases. Using `timeit.timeit()` to measure timings:

For a small array:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(400).reshape(20,20))
>>> timeit("x = df.T[:10].T", globals=globals(), number=100)
0.04253590002190322
>>> timeit("x = df.iloc[:,:10]", globals=globals(), number=100)
0.006828900019172579
```

For a large array, the difference is more noticeable:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(400000000).reshape(20000,20000))
>>> timeit("x = df.T[:10].T", globals=globals(), number=100)
0.5803892000112683
>>> timeit("x = df.iloc[:,:10]", globals=globals(), number=100)
0.00561390002258122
```

That's about 100x slower for the transpose approach.